# Create new R session matching details of previously saved sessionInfo() data

Tags: r

I'm starting work in a research environment where sharing the details for my coding and reproducibility is a priority. If I save the details of work on some project from sessionInfo(packages = NULL) to file, is there a way that I can have that data used to specify package versions to be used in future sessions?

Ideally, I'd like to write a script to go with the sessionInfo() data file so that if someone ran the script with the sessionInfo() file, all of the packages I used in that session would be loaded into there environment using the packages and package versions I used. I'm guessing I could parse the package names and versions from the sessionInfo() object and save that as a table but I wanted to check if there was an existing method to do this first.

Comment: Take a look at packages like [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html) or [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) which try to do all the package version management for you.

Comment: MrFlick’s answer is correct; reproducibility is a well-developed subject in R and you would do best to settle on an established solution. I would consider looking at the targets package as it provides a robust approach to managing reproducibility in research / analytical projects.